# Understanding raw_input function in Python

Tags: python, raw-input

I have the following code:

```
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
height = raw_input("How tall are you? ")
weight = raw_input("How much do you weigh? ")
print " So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." %(age, height, weight)
```

Ok so the `raw_input` function can standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

What I don't understand is why every prompt message is presented on a new line since raw_input only returns a string. It doesn't add a newline and I don't have any `\n` in the code.

Comment: When you enter the input, do you press the Enter key when you are done?

Comment: @murgatroid99: True, although one might think, as Enter "sends" the input to the application, that it is not part of the input anymore... but well... it is.

Comment: Is what you are looking for is to have all the prompts on the same line?  raw_input can't do that.  You could try curses or msvcrt on windows.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Like Felix Kling said, I thought Enter is not part of the input. Seems like I was wrong. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type a response to the raw_input() you finish by entering a newline. Since each character you enter is also displayed as you type, the newline shows up as well.

If you modified the python builtins and changed raw_input you could get it to terminate on '.' instead of '\n'. An interaction might look like:
`How old are you? 12.How tall are you? 12.How much do you weigh? 12. So you're ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in windows, using msvcrt.  You could do a similar thing on Mac or unix using curses library.

```
import msvcrt
import string

print("How old are you? "),
age = ''
key = ''
while key != '\r':
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    age += key
print("How tall are you? "),
key = ''
height = ''
while key != '\r':
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    height += key
print("How much do you weigh? "),
key = ''
weight = ''
while key != '\r':
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    weight += key
print "\n So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." %(string.strip(age), string.strip(height), string.strip(weight))
```

Sample output looks like this:

```
How old are you?  How tall are you?  How much do you weigh?
 So, you're '37' old, "6'" tall and '200' heavy.
```

Comment: You could have it echo back the characters to the screen as well, but notice it's not outputting the user's input until the end.